# Upload images from clipboard using jquery fileupload

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I want to upload an image using <kbd>ctrl + c</kbd> or <kbd>alt + PrtScr</kbd> command and then paste inside a container or multiple containers for uploading them on server. I am using an existing JQuery function (included below), but I am unable to code it. Please show me the way.

```
$(function(){  
var btnUpload=$('#upload');  
var status=$('#status');  
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {  
    action: 'upload-file.php',  
    //Name of the file input box  
    name: 'uploadfile',  
    onSubmit: function(file, ext){  
        if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){   
              // check for valid file extension   
            status.text('Only JPG, PNG or GIF files are allowed');  
            return false;  
        }  
        status.text('Uploading...');  
    },  
    onComplete: function(file, response){  
        //On completion clear the status  
        status.text('');  
        //Add uploaded file to list  
        if(response==="success"){  
            $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');  
        } else{  
            $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');  
        }  
    }  
});});
```

I will be grateful for any help provided.

Comment: What do you mean "I am unable to code it"? What exactly have you tried and what are the problems? What is happening and what have you expected to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to use the data in the clipboard you should check http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/

Basically, once you have got the data you´ll need a file interface to upload it.

for example:

```
file = item.getAsFile() -> Returns a File object
```

So you need to handle the pasted data in a similar way to obtain the file interface.

From: https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/upload-image-by-copy-and-paste/

```
function handlePaste(e) {
for (var i = 0 ; i < e.clipboardData.items.length ; i++) {
    var item = e.clipboardData.items[i];
    console.log("Item type: " + item.type);
    if (item.type.indexOf("image") != -1) {
        uploadFile(item.getAsFile());
    } else {
        console.log("Discarding non-image paste data");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but I already have made the application... But I will take it, it may help in some other way whenever needed. Thank you once again.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time you could answer your own question when you have solved it by yourself. As you have said, it may help other people.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('paste', '#file-input', function(e) {
  var items = (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
 for (index in items) {
var item = items[index];
if (item.kind === 'file') {
  var blob = item.getAsFile();
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    $('#image-preview').attr('src', event.target.result);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}}});
```